# The result of solve In Matlab turns out to be infinity

Tags: matlab, math

I have a program in Matlab to calculate the P for my strength of material class. In this case, P is the same all across the equation below. My program runs, however, it does not give me the result I want. If I perform this operation on paper, it would be

some value X times P = a value on the right hand side.

Then I could divided X both side to get the result of P. Please help, thanks !!

Code:

```
% Strength of Materials Project 1 syms p

 T = 100;

 EA = 10E-6; EB = 15E-6; ES = 28E-6;

 LS = 1; LA = 1; LB = 1; D  = 0.025;

 A = (pi/4) * D^2;

 dsteel = ES * T* LS; psteel = (p * LS)/(A * ES); 
 totalDeflectionSteel= dsteel - psteel;

 daluminum = EA * T * LA; paluminum = (p * LA)/(A * EA);
 totalDeflectionAluminum = daluminum - paluminum;

 dbrass = ES * T * LS; pbrass = (p * LB)/(A * EB); 

 totalDeflectionbrass = dbrass - pbrass;

 totalDeflection = totalDeflectionSteel + totalDeflectionAluminum +
 totalDeflectionbrass;

 answer = solve(totalDeflection == 0,p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with very small and very big numbers, and you probably didn't pay enough attention to the result (`answer` variable)... because it contains a division symbol (`/`). Given:

```
syms p;
```

if I run your code I obtain the following solution:

```
answer =
   724122253742406711011644945554203085511758135573 / 
   45234281407471544700030010881484741752481319554159476736000
```

When I evaluate it to a full numeric value using `double(answer)`, it turns out that the final result is `1.60082625657186e-11`... which seems to be much more coherent with your expectations.